# Relation between tables not stored first run

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

So I have this model:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
public class OrderResponse {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String referenceNumber;
    private String createdDate;
    private String modifiedDate;
    private double totalPrice;

    @Embedded
    private CollectionResponse lines;
```

And:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Embeddable
public class CollectionResponse {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<OrderLineResponse> items;
```

Basically, the CollectionRespone class is just a mapping of one OrderResponse, to a number of OrderLineResponses. I get this relationship from an external API in JSON format, and I'd like to avoid messing with the input format if possible, so that's why I don't just map it directly from OrderResponse to OrderLineResponse.

The current setup works mostly fine, with the correct tables being generated and populated. A table for the Order Responses, one for the OrdeLineResponses and a relational table. The thing is just, the relational table, for some reason, isn't being populated on the first call of my method, that should save to it, but always on subsequent calls.

My method looks like this.

```
public void addOrdersFromTo(String from, String to, int offset) throws Exception {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    params.add("start", from);
    params.add("end", to);
    params.add("include", "lines");
    params.add("offset", Integer.toString(offset));

    URI url = buildUrl("/admin/WEBAPI/v2/orders", params, uriComponentsBuilder);

    JsonNode jsonNode = restTemplate.getForObject(url, JsonNode.class);

    ObjectMapper jsonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Collection<OrderResponse> orderResponses = Arrays.asList(jsonObjectMapper.treeToValue(jsonNode.get("items"), OrderResponse[].class));

    orderResponseRepository.saveAll(orderResponses);
```

**EDIT:**
This is my OrderLineResponse entity, without getters and setters.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
public class OrderLineResponse {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String productNumber;
    private String productName;
    private int quantity;
    private double unitPrice;
    private double totalPrice;

    public OrderLineResponse() {
    }

    public OrderLineResponse(int id, String productNumber, String 
productName, int quantity, double unitPrice, double totalPrice) {
        this.id = id;
        this.productNumber = productNumber;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }
```

Comment: @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<OrderLineResponse> items;

shouldn't it be OrderResponse?

Comment: No, it's correct. OrderResponse contains a CollectionResponse, which contains a collection of OrderLineResponses.

Comment: If you have some entity `OrderLineResponse` then post it!

Comment: I added it now.